# Rails nested resources with strange path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a typical artist has_many songs model and I'm trying to set up the nested resource in Rails.

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
map.resources :artists do |artist|
   map.resources :songs
end
```

This works fine for the artist paths, but when I want to link to the songs controller, like this:

```
<%= link_to artist.name, artist_songs_path(artist) %>
```

my links look like this:

```
/songs.<artist:0x22b77ec>
```

Where it should probably look like `/artist/5/songs`

I'm sure it's something stupid I've missed, but I don't see it.  Ideas?

Comment: Doh!  as soon as I posted this I saw my error.  the nested route should be artist.resources :songs, not map.resources :songs.

Should I leave the question here for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm.... I think you should change map.resources :songs to artist.resources :songs...

Yes. leave the answer around. Maybe retag it with rails routes mistakes...